# C# NAudio for Windows 10 Universal App

Tags: c#, microsoft-metro, naudio

I am working on a universal platform app for windows targeted at windows 10. I mocked most of the logic up in a console application that is working fine, but I am getting an "Access is denied" exception trying to bring it into the metro system.

I've traced it down to the NAudio library which I am using to obtain a Wasapi loopback device. Everything works fine until I trigger the recording method on the Wasapi device.

This is my first metro app and I am a bit confused by the app manifest. Normally I would go add a elevated security privilege request in the manifest, but it would appear that I now need to work with "capabilities" and "declarations". I tried to add the background task audio declaration with my class library that is using NAudio as the entry point. I also tried enabling every capability listed as well. Neither of these methods have been successful.

As I said this is my first metro type application so this may be a trivial issue, but any advise or suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

**TLDR**; found the solution, enable microphone access to apps in system settings.

**Error trace for reference**: After a little (a lot of) digging I tracked down the exact error:

> An exception of type '**System.UnauthorizedAccessException**' occurred in **mscorlib.ni.dll** but was not handled in user code
>   Additional information: Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))

which was being thrown by ***Mmdevapi.dll***. NAudio / WASAPI loopback captures require the microphone capability which I did have enabled, but I disabled the microphone functionality system wide as a system preference. *System/Privacy/Microphone*. Changing this to allow apps to use the microphone fixed this issue.

Very silly, but caused me a lot of headache. Hope this saves someone else some time in the future.

Comment: Very interesting. is it possible you share your sources for this project? it would help me a lot!